# In AngularJS - Managing Multiple Panels for a True SPA

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm creating a true SPA application using AngularJS – there is only one view.

For each main feature of the application different panels (directives) will be displayed. Also, there are some common panels that will be shared across features. Below is an image of a contrived example. Notice that there are multiple panels on the view.

The short question is, when the user selects a specific feature (Airline, Hotels, Cars) how do I manage all the different panels that should be displayed and hidden?  If this was an application with multiple views I would use AngularJS routing, but not sure if this applies to an application that only has one view.

A couple of things to keep in mind:

- All my directives and services should continue to be testable
- If possible, I rather not use $broadcast for communication
- Should be able to use URL Routes

Are there any recommendations of how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given how you've tagged this question with ui-router shows that you're definitely on the right path. What you're looking for can be achieved in a clean manner by using [multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

> The short question is, when the user selects a specific feature
>   (Airline, Hotels, Cars) how do I manage all the different panels that
>   should be displayed and hidden?

Well given how you will have 3 base states, cars/hotels/airlines, then you will just show the view for that state when it is active, the multiple child views will be shown by default for that state. Look at the basic multiple named view demo:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('cars',{
    views: {
      'carsFilter': {
        templateUrl: 'car-filters.html',//or a common filters templare shared by all your states
        controller: function($scope){}
      },
      'carsSearch': {
        templateUrl: 'car-search.html',
        controller: function($scope){}
      },
      'carDetails': {
        templateUrl: 'car-details.html',
        controller: function($scope){}
      },
    }
  })
```

You would have that state for airlines and hotels, so handling the state changes is not something to worry about, unless I'm not fully understanding what you asked ;)

> If this was an application with multiple views I would use AngularJS
>   routing, but not sure if this applies to an application that only has
>   one view.

Well your application is not a single view app. You have that map (could be a base abstract state shared among your child states), you have the airlines/hotels/cars views, as well as the filters/details/search result views.